# how to use Textfield value in main class JavaJDK NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, java-6

i have a java that and thats work with success ! **https://pastebin.com/VbxeFKFz** now i want to make a simple form with jdk netbeans that contain 5 textfield and button and label to show result, but i have error, i think that happened because i use my method in Class Start , but i dont now how to use my method in main class ( my method + button and tools code )
My Code :

```
package knnjdk;
import java.util.*;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;


public class KnnJDK extends Application {

@Override

public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
    // Labels & inputs Settings
    Label number1 = new Label("Data 1 :");
    Label number2 = new Label("Data 2 :");
    Label number3 = new Label("Data 3 :");
    Label number4 = new Label("Data 4 :");
    Label number5 = new Label("Data 5 :");
    Label resultat1 = new Label("The Result");
    TextField txt1 = new TextField();
    TextField txt2 = new TextField();
    TextField txt3 = new TextField();
    TextField txt4 = new TextField();
    TextField txt5 = new TextField();
    grid.add(number1,0,0);
    grid.add(number2,0,1);
    grid.add(number3,0,2);
    grid.add(number4,0,3);
    grid.add(number5,0,4);
    grid.add(resultat1,0,6);
    grid.add(txt1,1,0);
    grid.add(txt2,1,1);
    grid.add(txt3,1,2);
    grid.add(txt4,1,3);
    grid.add(txt5,1,4);
    Button butt = new Button();
    butt.setText("Applique KPPV");
    grid.add(butt,0,5);
    // My Main Method
    ///////////////////////////////////
    double insertedInt = Double.parseDouble(txt1.getText());
    double insertedInt2 = Double.parseDouble(txt2.getText());
    double insertedInt3 = Double.parseDouble(txt3.getText());
    double insertedInt4 = Double.parseDouble(txt4.getText());
    double insertedInt5 = Double.parseDouble(txt5.getText());
    double[] query = {insertedInt, insertedInt2, insertedInt3, insertedInt4, insertedInt5};

    int k = 10;// K : Welaya List Counts  
    List<City> cityList = new ArrayList<City>();
    List<Result> resultList = new ArrayList<Result>();   
    cityList.add(new City(instances[0],"IRIS0"));
    cityList.add(new City(instances[1],"IRIS1"));
    cityList.add(new City(instances[2],"IRIS2"));
    cityList.add(new City(instances[3],"IRIS3"));
    cityList.add(new City(instances[4],"IRIS4"));
    cityList.add(new City(instances[5],"IRIS5"));
    cityList.add(new City(instances[6],"IRIS6"));
    cityList.add(new City(instances[7],"IRIS7"));
    cityList.add(new City(instances[8],"IRIS8"));
    cityList.add(new City(instances[9],"IRIS9"));
    //find distances
    for(City city : cityList){
        double dist = 0.0;  
        for(int j = 0; j < city.cityAttributes.length; j++){             
            dist += Math.pow(city.cityAttributes[j] - query[j], 2) ;
        }
        double distance = Math.sqrt( dist );
        resultList.add(new Result(distance,city.cityName));

    } 


    Collections.sort(resultList, new DistanceComparator());
    String[] ss = new String[k];
    for(int x = 0; x < k; x++){
        ss[x] = resultList.get(x).cityName;
    }
    String majClass = findMajorityClass(ss);
    //System.out.println("The Nearest IRIS Class is : "+majClass);   



    ///////////////////////////////////
    Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 250);


    // Final Action
    butt.setOnAction(event->{
        resultat1.setText(majClass);
    });
    primaryStage.setTitle("KNN With JDK");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();

}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);

}
// My Method
// our Data Base
static double[][] instances = {
        {6.300000,2.500000,5.000000,1.900000,3.000000},
        {6.900000,3.200000,5.700000,2.300000,3.000000},
        {5.100000,3.800000,1.900000,0.400000,1.000000},
        {6.600000,2.900000,4.600000,1.300000,2.000000},
        {5.700000,4.400000,1.500000,0.400000,1.000000},
        {4.600000,3.400000,1.400000,0.300000,1.000000},
        {4.300000,3.000000,1.100000,0.100000,1.000000},
        {6.900000,3.100000,5.100000,2.300000,3.000000},
        {5.100000,3.700000,1.500000,0.400000,1.000000},
        {6.100000,2.800000,4.700000,1.200000,2.000000},

};
private static String findMajorityClass(String[] array)
{
    //add the String array to a HashSet to get unique String values
    Set<String> h = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
    //convert the HashSet back to array
    String[] uniqueValues = h.toArray(new String[0]);
    //counts for unique strings
    int[] counts = new int[uniqueValues.length];
    // loop thru unique strings and count how many times they appear in origianl array   
    for (int i = 0; i < uniqueValues.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            if(array[j].equals(uniqueValues[i])){
                counts[i]++;
            }
        }        
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < uniqueValues.length; i++)
        System.out.println(uniqueValues[i]);
    for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
        System.out.println(counts[i]);


    int max = counts[0];
    for (int counter = 1; counter < counts.length; counter++) {
        if (counts[counter] > max) {
            max = counts[counter];
        }
    }
    System.out.println("max # of occurences: "+max);
    int freq = 0;
    for (int counter = 0; counter < counts.length; counter++) {
        if (counts[counter] == max) {
            freq++;
        }
    }
    int index = -1;
    if(freq==1){
        for (int counter = 0; counter < counts.length; counter++) {
            if (counts[counter] == max) {
                index = counter;
                break;
            }
        }
        //System.out.println("one majority class, index is: "+index);
        return uniqueValues[index];
    } else{//we have multiple modes
        int[] ix = new int[freq];//array of indices of modes
        System.out.println("multiple majority classes: "+freq+" classes");
        int ixi = 0;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < counts.length; counter++) {
            if (counts[counter] == max) {
                ix[ixi] = counter;//save index of each max count value
                ixi++; // increase index of ix array
            }
        }

        for (int counter = 0; counter < ix.length; counter++)         
            System.out.println("class index: "+ix[counter]);       

        //now choose one at random
        Random generator = new Random();        
        //get random number 0 <= rIndex < size of ix
        int rIndex = generator.nextInt(ix.length);
        System.out.println("random index: "+rIndex);
        int nIndex = ix[rIndex];
        //return unique value at that index 
        return uniqueValues[nIndex];
    }

}



private static double meanOfArray(double[] m) {
    double sum = 0.0;
    for (int j = 0; j < m.length; j++){
        sum += m[j];
    }
    return sum/m.length;
}






//simple class to model instances (features + class)
static class City { 
    double[] cityAttributes;
    String cityName;
    public City(double[] cityAttributes, String cityName){
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.cityAttributes = cityAttributes;               
    }
}
//simple class to model results (distance + class)
static class Result {   
    double distance;
    String cityName;
    public Result(double distance, String cityName){
        this.cityName = cityName;
        this.distance = distance;               
    }
}
//simple comparator class used to compare results via distances
static class DistanceComparator implements Comparator<Result> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Result a, Result b) {
        return a.distance < b.distance ? -1 : a.distance == b.distance ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

}

the errror :

```
 Exception in Application start method
 java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at                           sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at      sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.jav     a:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at           com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.j     ava:389)
 at      com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Comment: Could you post something more [mcve] ? This would be fantastic :) And of course, what is the **error** you get ? Explain the problem fully with the smallest example possible.

Comment: i have add the error, alse just copie the code and paste it in netbeans and run u will see the same error, that make me confuse :(

Comment: See [ask], you have to provide every information in the question. If we have to paste every code to get the information that you don't provide, this would become really unpleasant for us to provide our help.

Comment: your code doesnt even compile with copy and paste. probably you want to use `JTextField` and `JLabel` as well as `JButton` and `GridLayout` (instead of GridPane)

Comment: sorry, now i have update u code and u can use it and see the error, alse can u give me an example how to use Jbutton ?

Comment: same as button but i think its more common. your problem seems to be that you have logic and gui in 1 class. you should separate that. ` Double.parseDouble(txt1.getText());` is one of your problems, because you have no string in your textfield. you should move your logic in an actionlistener, so it only gets executed if you press a button. since we don't know what the program should do, we can't provide a working solution. one thing you can do is to set the text to a default. ill post an answer shortly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Etst extends Application {

    @Override

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        GridPane grid = new GridPane();
        // Labels & inputs Settings
        Label number1 = new Label("Data 1 :");
        Label number2 = new Label("Data 2 :");
        Label number3 = new Label("Data 3 :");
        Label number4 = new Label("Data 4 :");
        Label number5 = new Label("Data 5 :");
        Label resultat1 = new Label("The Result");
        TextField txt1 = new TextField();
        TextField txt2 = new TextField();
        TextField txt3 = new TextField();
        TextField txt4 = new TextField();
        TextField txt5 = new TextField();
        grid.add(number1, 0, 0);
        grid.add(number2, 0, 1);
        grid.add(number3, 0, 2);
        grid.add(number4, 0, 3);
        grid.add(number5, 0, 4);
        grid.add(resultat1, 0, 6);
        grid.add(txt1, 1, 0);
        grid.add(txt2, 1, 1);
        grid.add(txt3, 1, 2);
        grid.add(txt4, 1, 3);
        grid.add(txt5, 1, 4);
        Button butt = new Button();
        butt.setText("Applique KPPV");
        grid.add(butt, 0, 5);
        // My Main Method
        ///////////////////////////////////


        // ADDED THESE 5 LINES. NOW IT SHOWS A WINDOW WITH THESE VALUES FILLED IN
        txt1.setText("0.0");
        txt2.setText("0.0");
        txt3.setText("0.0");
        txt4.setText("0.0");
        txt5.setText("0.0");

        double insertedInt = Double.parseDouble(txt1.getText());
        double insertedInt2 = Double.parseDouble(txt2.getText());
        double insertedInt3 = Double.parseDouble(txt3.getText());
        double insertedInt4 = Double.parseDouble(txt4.getText());
        double insertedInt5 = Double.parseDouble(txt5.getText());
        double[] query = { insertedInt, insertedInt2, insertedInt3, insertedInt4, insertedInt5 };

        int k = 10;// K : Welaya List Counts
        List<City> cityList = new ArrayList<City>();
        List<Result> resultList = new ArrayList<Result>();
        cityList.add(new City(instances[0], "IRIS0"));
        cityList.add(new City(instances[1], "IRIS1"));
        cityList.add(new City(instances[2], "IRIS2"));
        cityList.add(new City(instances[3], "IRIS3"));
        cityList.add(new City(instances[4], "IRIS4"));
        cityList.add(new City(instances[5], "IRIS5"));
        cityList.add(new City(instances[6], "IRIS6"));
        cityList.add(new City(instances[7], "IRIS7"));
        cityList.add(new City(instances[8], "IRIS8"));
        cityList.add(new City(instances[9], "IRIS9"));
        // find distances
        for (City city : cityList) {
            double dist = 0.0;
            for (int j = 0; j < city.cityAttributes.length; j++) {
                dist += Math.pow(city.cityAttributes[j] - query[j], 2);
            }
            double distance = Math.sqrt(dist);
            resultList.add(new Result(distance, city.cityName));

        }

        Collections.sort(resultList, new DistanceComparator());
        String[] ss = new String[k];
        for (int x = 0; x < k; x++) {
            ss[x] = resultList.get(x).cityName;
        }
        String majClass = findMajorityClass(ss);
        // System.out.println("The Nearest IRIS Class is : "+majClass);

        ///////////////////////////////////
        Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 300, 250);

        // Final Action
        butt.setOnAction(event -> {
            resultat1.setText(majClass);
        });
        primaryStage.setTitle("KNN With JDK");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     *            the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);

    }

    // My Method
    // our Data Base
    static double[][] instances = { { 6.300000, 2.500000, 5.000000, 1.900000, 3.000000 },
            { 6.900000, 3.200000, 5.700000, 2.300000, 3.000000 }, { 5.100000, 3.800000, 1.900000, 0.400000, 1.000000 },
            { 6.600000, 2.900000, 4.600000, 1.300000, 2.000000 }, { 5.700000, 4.400000, 1.500000, 0.400000, 1.000000 },
            { 4.600000, 3.400000, 1.400000, 0.300000, 1.000000 }, { 4.300000, 3.000000, 1.100000, 0.100000, 1.000000 },
            { 6.900000, 3.100000, 5.100000, 2.300000, 3.000000 }, { 5.100000, 3.700000, 1.500000, 0.400000, 1.000000 },
            { 6.100000, 2.800000, 4.700000, 1.200000, 2.000000 },

    };

    private static String findMajorityClass(String[] array) {
        // add the String array to a HashSet to get unique String values
        Set<String> h = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(array));
        // convert the HashSet back to array
        String[] uniqueValues = h.toArray(new String[0]);
        // counts for unique strings
        int[] counts = new int[uniqueValues.length];
        // loop thru unique strings and count how many times they appear in
        // origianl array
        for (int i = 0; i < uniqueValues.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
                if (array[j].equals(uniqueValues[i])) {
                    counts[i]++;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < uniqueValues.length; i++)
            System.out.println(uniqueValues[i]);
        for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
            System.out.println(counts[i]);

        int max = counts[0];
        for (int counter = 1; counter < counts.length; counter++) {
            if (counts[counter] > max) {
                max = counts[counter];
            }
        }
        System.out.println("max # of occurences: " + max);
        int freq = 0;
        for (int counter = 0; counter < counts.length; counter++) {
            if (counts[counter] == max) {
                freq++;
            }
        }
        int index = -1;
        if (freq == 1) {
            for (int counter = 0; counter < counts.length; counter++) {
                if (counts[counter] == max) {
                    index = counter;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // System.out.println("one majority class, index is: "+index);
            return uniqueValues[index];
        } else {// we have multiple modes
            int[] ix = new int[freq];// array of indices of modes
            System.out.println("multiple majority classes: " + freq + " classes");
            int ixi = 0;
            for (int counter = 0; counter < counts.length; counter++) {
                if (counts[counter] == max) {
                    ix[ixi] = counter;// save index of each max count value
                    ixi++; // increase index of ix array
                }
            }

            for (int counter = 0; counter < ix.length; counter++)
                System.out.println("class index: " + ix[counter]);

            // now choose one at random
            Random generator = new Random();
            // get random number 0 <= rIndex < size of ix
            int rIndex = generator.nextInt(ix.length);
            System.out.println("random index: " + rIndex);
            int nIndex = ix[rIndex];
            // return unique value at that index
            return uniqueValues[nIndex];
        }

    }

    private static double meanOfArray(double[] m) {
        double sum = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < m.length; j++) {
            sum += m[j];
        }
        return sum / m.length;
    }

    // simple class to model instances (features + class)
    static class City {
        double[] cityAttributes;
        String cityName;

        public City(double[] cityAttributes, String cityName) {
            this.cityName = cityName;
            this.cityAttributes = cityAttributes;
        }
    }

    // simple class to model results (distance + class)
    static class Result {
        double distance;
        String cityName;

        public Result(double distance, String cityName) {
            this.cityName = cityName;
            this.distance = distance;
        }
    }

    // simple comparator class used to compare results via distances
    static class DistanceComparator implements Comparator<Result> {
        @Override
        public int compare(Result a, Result b) {
            return a.distance < b.distance ? -1 : a.distance == b.distance ? 0 : 1;
        }
    }

}
```

i just set the initial text of the textfields so it doesn't throw an error. this is not a a good style to program, because you mix gui and business logic. maybe you should refactor your whole program

Comment: no problem. do you understand why it threw an error?

Comment: okay, you created a textfield with `TextField txt1 = new TextField();`. now its existing, but doesn't hold any data eg. a string, but in this line `double insertedInt = Double.parseDouble(txt1.getText());` you access the content with `txt1.getText()` which is neither a number nor anything else (its empty) and thus you get the error which was a NumberFormatException. this means, that the program can't parse the string into an number. `12.0` would work while `asdf` wouldn't because its not representing a number. you didn't post the whole stacktrace and thus it was a bit harder to find.